Event working but class not reacting to the event
In my website, when you click in an element, an nav list open just above. This list closes when the user clicks in another part of the page (body), scroll the page (body) and when clicks again in the element named "Produtos".
I did the body part and with the last one it isn't working!


let listaProdutos = document.querySelector(".lista-produtos");
let checkBoxProdutos = document.querySelector("#menu");
let produtos = document.getElementById("link-produtos");

checkBoxProdutos.addEventListener("change", function () {
  x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 849px)");
  if (x.matches) {
    if (this.checked) {
      listaProdutos.classList.add("visivel");
      listaProdutos.classList.remove("invisivel");

      // Para fechar a lista:
      let body = document.querySelector("body");
      body.addEventListener("click", function () {
        listaProdutos.classList.add("invisivel");
        listaProdutos.classList.remove("visivel");
        checkBoxProdutos.checked = true;
      });
      body.addEventListener("mousewheel", function () {
        listaProdutos.classList.add("invisivel");
        listaProdutos.classList.remove("visivel");
      });

      produtos.addEventListener("click", function () {
        alert("ola");
        listaProdutos.classList.add("invisivel");
        listaProdutos.classList.remove("visivel");
      });
    } else {
      listaProdutos.classList.add("invisivel");
      listaProdutos.classList.remove("visivel");
    }
  }
});
.visivel {
  display: block;
}

.invisivel {
  display: none;
}
<div class="cabecalho-lista">
  <ul class="cabecalho__lista">
    <li class="cabecalho__item">
      <a class="cabecalho__item__link" href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <div class="cabecalho__item-produtos">
      <li class="cabecalho__item cabecalho__item__produtos">
        <input class="produtos-celular" type="checkbox" id="menu" />
        <label for="menu">
          <a
            class="cabecalho__item__link"
            id="link-produtos"
            href="produtos.html"
            >Produtos</a
          >
        </label>

        <ul class="lista-produtos invisivel">
          <li class="lista-produtos__item">
            <a href="produtos.html#ignite">Linha Ignite</a>
          </li>
          <li class="lista-produtos__item">
            <a href="produtos.html#elfbar">Linha Elfbar</a>
          </li>
          <li class="lista-produtos__item">
            <a href="produtos.html#oxbar">Linha Oxbar</a>
          </li>
          <li class="lista-produtos__item">
            <a href="produtos.html#lost">Linha Lost Mary</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </div>
    <li class="cabecalho__item">
      <a class="cabecalho__item__link" href="contato.html">FAQ</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>



When the listener are listening click in "produtos", the alert works well but the class that cleans the nav list simple doesnt work!
The list only disappear when the user scrool or click the body.

What is the class that cleans the nav list ?

When I run it, x.matches is false, so invisivel is added (and already exists) and visivel is removed (doesn't exist on the element), so I wouldn't expect anything to change. What steps have you taken to debug this?

FYI, your HTML is invalid. A list item must be the child of a list element. I suggest a good editor or an HTML validator.

Protip: All your elements can be assigned with const instead of let.

Is the media query relevant to the question? If not, remove it from the snippet so people on mobile devices (like @mykaf) can run it.

It's generally a bad idea to add event listeners inside other event listeners. Every time you click on the checkbox you add duplicate event listeners to the body and produtos.

FWIW, I was running in JSFiddle, but IDK how or where OP was running it and could have been encountering the same issue.

This question is similar to: JS, click event and class. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The first thing to do here is fix your invalid HTML. A <ul> or <ol> may not have div children. The div would have to exist within a <li>.
Next, simplify:

You don't need a CSS class to hide something and another one to show
something. You only need one for hiding things and when you want
something to be visible, just remove the one that hides it.
And since you'll only have one class to control display, you can just
toggle it, rather than using if/then to determine if it should be
displayed or not.
Not sure what the media query has to do with this, but get the basic
code working first and then you can add additional requirements.

Finally, avoid setting up event handlers within event handlers. This can easily  create problems with multiple event handlers getting "stacked" up on top of each other.
See the code below and comments:


const listaProdutos = document.querySelector(".lista-produtos");
const checkBoxProdutos = document.querySelector("#menu");
const produtos = document.getElementById("link-produtos");

checkBoxProdutos.addEventListener("click", function () {
  // You don't need to explicitly make something visible.
  // Just remove the CSS that was making it invisible.
  // You also don't need to check for whether to hide or show it.
  // Just toggle the use of the class that is hiding it.
  listaProdutos.classList.toggle("invisivel");
});

// Set up handlers for clicks outside of the list and scrolling
document.addEventListener("click", function(){hideList(event)});
document.addEventListener("mousewheel", function(){hideList(event)});

function hideList(evt) {
  // If the clicked element isn't a descendant of a <ul>...
  if(!evt.target.closest("ul")){
    listaProdutos.classList.add("invisivel");   // Hide the list
    checkBoxProdutos.checked = false;           // Reset the checkbox    
  }
}
/* You only need a class to hide things. 
   Just remove it when you want to show things. */
.invisivel { display: none; }
<div class="cabecalho-lista">
  <ul class="cabecalho__lista">
    <li class="cabecalho__item">
      <a class="cabecalho__item__link" href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="cabecalho__item cabecalho__item__produtos">
      <div class="cabecalho__item-produtos">
        <input class="produtos-celular" type="checkbox" id="menu">
        <label for="menu">
          <a class="cabecalho__item__link" id="link-produtos"
             href="produtos.html">Produtos</a>
        </label>
        <ul class="lista-produtos invisivel">
          <li class="lista-produtos__item">
            <a href="produtos.html#ignite">Linha Ignite</a>
          </li>
          <li class="lista-produtos__item">
            <a href="produtos.html#elfbar">Linha Elfbar</a>
          </li>
          <li class="lista-produtos__item">
            <a href="produtos.html#oxbar">Linha Oxbar</a>
          </li>
          <li class="lista-produtos__item">
            <a href="produtos.html#lost">Linha Lost Mary</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="cabecalho__item">
      <a class="cabecalho__item__link" href="contato.html">FAQ</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>




Scott, thank you so much for the advice!
I fixed what you said, but the error continues.
With the listening in the document, any click in the page closes the list, except the tag  Produtos  :/
I dont know why! When I put the click event in the  tag, he does an alert, for example, but doesnt add the "invisivel" class.

@user26579796 Please clarify. You want the top-level item "Products" to disappear as well? That doesn't seem correct to me, but if that's what you want, you need to separate the checkbox and the li so that the checkbox is outside of <div class="cabecalho__item-produtos"> and it's <div class="cabecalho__item-produtos"> that gets hidden.

@user26579796 Also, if the user clicks the a, then they are going to be navigated away from the current page, so trying to hide the list is pointless.
